# How to restore emails on CentOS?

Tags: linux, centos

I moved my domain to another server.
Unfortunately, i deleted the emails accounts from my Mail Client (On MAC) and all of the previous emails have been deleted and I don't have access to them. How may I restore them again?
Actually I would like to restore all the emails that have been received on my previous CentOS server.
The mail server was Exim and I have access to the server, please also consider that the server was installed with cPanel.

Thanks

Comment: How is this programming related?

Comment: @PeeHaa Did you *not see* the linux-kernal tag?

Comment: Do you have access to the old server still?   Was it providing your MTA services?  What mail server?

Comment: @MikeB: There's a specific site for [Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) questions. This question has nothing to do with code.

Comment: @ficuscr Yes I do, It should be default Mail server which will be insalled with cPanel, sorry I forgot it.

Answer (score 1):

Given

- An Exim e-mail server (MTA) running on a Centos Linux server.
- An e-mail client (MUA) running on Mac OSX.

Assuming you either

- accessed your MTA using `POP3` and didn't configure the MUA to delete old mail from the server after each download from the server. Or
- accessed your MTA using `IMAP` and didn't explicitly delete the mail from IMAP folders using the MUA.

The old mail may be in one of

- `~/Maildir/name`
- `~/imap/example.com/Maildir/name`

Otherwise the mail messages are probably gone (assuming you have no backups of server or Mac).

Note:

So far as I know, Exim provides SMTP (inbound or outbound or both) and delivery into local mailboxes on the server. For POP3/IMAP you probably have/had a suitable POP3/IMAP service such as Dovecot installed on the server. This shouldn't affect the answer.

Comment: Where is the ~/Maildir/name?  You mean on MAC or CentOS server? Please note that I used POP3 .

Comment: @Navidos: on the CentOS server. If you used POP3 it is likely your Mac's email client was configured to delete mail from the server after downloading mail to your Mac. So there'd be nothing left on the server  after you deleted the mail on the Mac. I'm not a Mac user but there may be a small chance the local mail folders still exist on the Mac if you just deleted the mail *account* from the Mac mail client without explicitly deleting the local mail-folders.